# Should SharePoint specific questions be flagged for migration?

Tags: discussion

The review system has been showing me many SharePoint specific questions today ([example 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/77572/enabling-office-sharepoint-server-publishing-infrastructure-breaks-navigation), [example 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/178833/view-web-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010-central-administration)). Most of these questions look like they'd be more appropriate for https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/. Should I flag them for migration?

Answer (score 7):

One thing I'll note now, and it's a general thing but appropriate since we now have several sharepoint-migration flags right now, I don't migrate questions to other sites if:

- The question is too old (if it is more than 6 months old, I generally don't bother unless there is something specific about it). In that case it'll get an OT close if it gets anything.
- It was well answered here.

Comment: A while ago I asked the guys on DBA about sending some of the old unloved database related questions over and they requested nothing older than 6 months too.

Comment: Agreed -- Older questions and ones that have accepted answers should remain. New questions that are very Sharepoint-specific or those that don't get good answers here should be migrated to hopefully get some love.

Comment: Why wouldn't you migrate them if they have good answers? Do the answers not migrate with the question?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should vote to close if such questions do not have an accepted answer and are more than six months old. Is that correct, or should I leave them alone?

Comment: Vote-to-close works for those, especially if you have a cabal you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

I would. If the site is there it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Just because there is a SharePoint site is not enough reason to migrate SharePoint questions.

If we keep migrating questions to what might be perceived as more appropriate sites where will that eventually leave SF? I seems to me that a lot of content that is perfectly on topic for SF has been getting migrated for no reason other than there are sites catering to specific topics. This doesn't help SF at all and is actually quite detrimental.

Comment: Your answer puzzles me. The sites act as a form of broad categorization. What's the point of have separate sites if we aren't going to move questions that are more appropriate for a different site to those sites? We don't do the submitter any favors by keeping those questions here instead of sending them to the site with a higher number of subject matter experts. Shouldn't our goal be to make sure that the submitter gets the best answer they possibly can by exposing it those experts? There will still be plenty of relevant questions for SF to cover.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the people sharepoint.stackexchange will probably have deeper understanding of sharepoint.